# What's the meaning of double underscore when naming a function

Tags: powershell

I see people having `__` in their function name in PowerShell, for example, `__APP-DateTimeToString`. They still have other functions following naming convention with approved verbs like `Do-Something`

Is that a personal style or a kind of coding practice?

Comment: The best people to ask would be the authors of the code in question - one reason could be they write script modules with many functions, and rather than keeping track of which functions should be exported by the module, they rely on non-standard naming schemes to distinguished between public vs private functions.

Comment: Do you mean dashes or underscores?  So programming languages will remove the dashes when use as a parameter so when using with PS you need to have two dashes.

Comment: @jdweng, the question is about the names of _functions_, not parameters, and it clearly shows _underscores_ (unless you go out of your way both during defining and calling, a function name cannot start with a _dash_ (hyphen)). Even if this question _were_ about parameters, it's not clear what you're trying to say. `--` followed by a word (e.g. `--foo`) has _no_ special meaning in PowerShell. However, there is `--` _in isolation_, which tells PowerShell's parameter binder to treat all subsequent arguments as _positional_ ones, even if they look like parameter names (e.g., `-foo`).